# EXTJS 4.0 Grid Filter Type Numeric Symbols not appearing

Tags: extjs

I have a problem in EXTJS 4.0 Grid Filter Type = numeric. Symbols of < > and = are not appearing. Screen shot attached.

[image: Image EXTJS4.0]

Comment: Did you check in the dev console or firebug what exactly is on the page? Is it problem of rendering some symbols or ExtJs doesn't include them into the page code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check source code (firebug),
There is special css file RangeMenu Styles
And images has background style

```
.ux-rangemenu-icon {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.ux-rangemenu-gt {
    background-image: url(../images/greater_than.png) !important;
}
.ux-rangemenu-lt {
    background-image: url(../images/less_than.png) !important;
}
.ux-rangemenu-eq {
    background-image: url(../images/equals.png) !important;
}
```

Check if You have them at images directory

Answer (score 2):

Simply add this in your file ,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../extjs/examples/ux/grid/css/RangeMenu.css"/>
```